# Upload multiple images on server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i was trying to code a form that helps in uploading images, after a little research over this site i had this script, however it is uploading only single image whereas i wish to upload multiple images on server folder and store their path in database table

```
<form action="insertimages.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Upload Image:</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input class="form-control" name="file" id="file" value="" type="file" multiple required>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
<div class="submit">
<input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save " type="submit" name="submit">
</div>  
</div>
</form>
```

Code of insertimages.php page is

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
            {
                echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            } 
        else 
            {
                if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
                    {
                        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    } 
                else 
                    {

                        $imagepath = "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imagepath);
                        $sql="INSERT INTO images(image,studentid) VALUES ('".$imagepath."','".$_SESSION['insert_id']."')";
                        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
                            {
                                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                            }
                    }
            }
            header("Location: index.php");
    } 
else    
    {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }

?>
```

can anyone rectify the error and help me

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 image because you only insert 1 image in the server you will need to loop your file like so :

```
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{

    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    //You need to handle  both cases
    //If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData() 
    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
        $ret[]= $fileName;
    }
    else  //Multiple files, file[]
    {
      $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
      for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
      {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
        $ret[]= $fileName;
      }

    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
 }
```

**NOTE** This is a sample code from a multi-uoploader as you see on this line : `if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]))`

there's a validation if the $_file is a array. If it's a array This is the loop that will upload image to the server :

```
for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
      {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
        $ret[]= $fileName;
      }
```

As you can see there isn't any msql insert in this sample so don't forget to ajust you own code to this exemple. You code should look like this :

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    //Replace $mysqli with your $con then. $con->query($sql);   
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  
        {
            if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
                {
                    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                } 
            else 
                {
                    if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
                        {
                            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                        } 
                    else 
                        {
                           if(!is_array($_FILES["file"]["name"])) //single file
                           {
                                $imagepath = "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $imagepath);
                                $sql="INSERT INTO images(image,studentid) VALUES ('".$imagepath."','".$_SESSION['insert_id']."')";
                                if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
                                    {
                                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                    }
                            }else  //Multiple files, file[]
                            {
                              $fileCount = count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                              for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
                              {
                                $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$i];
                                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i],$imagepath);
                                $ret[]= $fileName;
                                $sql="INSERT INTO images(image,studentid) VALUES ('".$imagepath."','".$_SESSION['insert_id']."')";
                                    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
                                    {
                                        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                                    }
                              }

                            }

                            }
                        }
                }
                header("Location: index.php");
        } 
    else    
        {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: it is still uploading single image only

Comment: Track If you pass in the `if(!is_array($_FILES["file"]["name"]))` processus or in the else processus ?

Answer (score 0):

the code you are using requires many changes because there are some unnecessory code is also there. You require the loop to upload all the image on server as well as to insert on database. I have do some refinements on your script.

### index.php

```
<form action="insertimages.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Upload Image:</label>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple/>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
<div class="submit">
<input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save " type="submit" name="submit">
</div>  
</div>
</form>
```

### insertimages.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysqldba","stackoverflow");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
//Replace $mysqli with your $con then. $con->query($sql);   

foreach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
$file_name = $key.$_FILES['file']['name'][$key];
$file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'][$key];   
if (
($file_type !== "image/gif")
|| ($file_type !== "image/jpeg")
|| ($file_type !== "image/jpg")
|| ($file_type !== "image/pjpeg")
|| ($file_type !== "image/x-png")
|| ($file_type !== "image/png"))
 {        
                if (file_exists("images/" . $file_name)) 
                    {
                        echo $file_name . " already exists. "; exit;
                    } 
                else 
                    {

                        $imagepath = "images/" . $file_name;
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $imagepath);
                        $sql="INSERT INTO images(image,studentid) VALUES ('".$imagepath."','".$_SESSION['insert_id']."')";
                        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
                            {
                                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                            }
                    }           
    } 
else    
    {
        echo "Invalid file"; exit;
    }
}


header("Location: index.php");


?>
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: i am getting this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()